# How do I write this html as php

Tags: php, html, variables

All of this needs to be inside my loop so I don't know if I can break it (don't think I can) but I need PHP to read it as HTML.

```
$movieDetails = 
<header class="masthead" role="banner">
        <div class="logo-container">
    <a class="logo" href="">Movie Details</a>
        </div>
</header>
        <div class="bubble-container">
            <div class="speech-bubble speech-bubble-top">
    Text that goes into the bubble
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: You want to echo the HTML? So: $movieDetails = '<header... </div>'; (note the simple quotes)

Answer (score 3):

You can just close your PHP tag to render text that will display as HTML.

```
<?php
foreach($movies as $movie) {
?>
   <div>
     <?php echo htmlspecialchars($movie); ?>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Beware of XSS: use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting text in an HTML context.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel That has nothing to do with the question though. The information in question isn't coming from a user as far as the OP's post indicates, and that would apply to any user submitted data.

Comment: @Jessica Information in a database *can* be from a user and it can legitimately contain characters like `<` and `&`.

Comment: I'm just saying that isn't what he asked about. You said beware of XSS. Legitimate uses of characters are not XSS.

Comment: @Jessica You're right, but things will be screwed anyhow if those characters are used.

Answer (score 2):

```
$movieDetails = <<<HTML
<header class="masthead" role="banner">
        <div class="logo-container">
    <a class="logo" href="">Movie Details</a>
        </div>
</header>
        <div class="bubble-container">
            <div class="speech-bubble speech-bubble-top">
    Text that goes into the bubble
            </div> 
        </div>
HTML;

echo $movieDetails;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: That's rather cumbersome to echo out HTML.

Comment: It is, but that's what he asked for. And actually, using HEREDOC syntax for this sort of thing is easier than quotes.

Comment: What is the "correct" thing I should do? What I am attempting to do is grab a movie bio for each movie matching the name of the movie. This HTML section is what causes the bubble to hover when your mouse goes over the word bio or whatever I set it as. I will actually change the "text that goes into the bubble" to some variable which actually grabs that movies text.

Comment: @JoeSalmi That depends on what you want to do; to me, your question is not clear, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: edited previous comment as you were typing haha

Comment: I am trying to add this to my [page](http://jsfiddle.net/LTSSx/25/) and it's all ran inside a loop so it will generate the same display word "Movie Bio" but on hover it will show the bio for the movie name that is on the same line. @MarcelKorpel

Comment: OP you need to read some basic PHP tutorials.

Comment: I'm working on @jessica thank you.